# How to arrange a website deployment with Ansible such that Apache is not restarted if there is no vhost change?

Tags: apache, ansible, vhosts

I am presently learning Ansible, and to apply what I am learning, I am converting some old Bash install scripts to build a web server. One of my use cases is to install or upgrade a website. The process generally is:

- Copy Apache vhost definition into `/etc/apache2/available-sites`
- Symlink vhost definition in `/etc/apache2/enabled-sites`
- Checkout branch in `/var/www/sitename` or copy from source folder
- Run custom set-up or migration scripts inside that project e.g. with Phing
- Graceful restart of Apache

I would be interested in only doing the web-server restart if the vhost is required, mainly because I have a passphrase on my SSL certificate, and this will need to be re-entered if that happens. Since most runs of this playbook will be upgrades and not installations, it makes sense to suppress the restart where it is not required.

I've done some searching around this use-case, but I can't seem to find much related material online. I have therefore creating the following, using a file hash to detect changes, and I am wondering if there is a better way to do it. Here it is:

```
---

# Copy site contents unconditionally
- file: path=/var/www/html state=directory
- copy: src=../../build-files/default/index.html dest=/var/www/html/index.html

# Copy vhost to a temporary file so we can checksum it remotely
- copy: src=../../build-files/apache/000-default.conf dest=/tmp/000-default.conf

# Get the checksum of the existing vhost
- shell: md5sum /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf | cut -f 1 -d ' '
  register: old_checksum_default_site

# Get the checksum of the new vhost
- shell: md5sum /tmp/000-default.conf | cut -f 1 -d ' '
  register: new_checksum_default_site

- debug: msg="Old checksum is {{ old_checksum_default_site.stdout }}, new checksum is {{ new_checksum_default_site.stdout }}"

# Copy our default vhost into place if necessary
- copy: src=../../build-files/apache/000-default.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
  notify: restart apache
  when: old_checksum_default_site.stdout != new_checksum_default_site.stdout
```

That's quite a bit of boilerplate to do for all sites, and it doesn't even symlink yet - is there a shorter way? I am not a Python programmer, but do let me know if writing a custom module might be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without knowing the internals of apache/vhost stuff, this should be enough

```
# Copy site contents unconditionally
- file: path=/var/www/html state=directory
- copy: src=../../build-files/default/index.html dest=/var/www/html/index.html

# Copy vhost to a temporary file so we can checksum it remotely
- copy: src=../../build-files/apache/000-default.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
  notify:
    - restart apache
```

If there are no changes to your local copy of `000-default.conf` then the ansible step will be reported as green when you run it.

If something has changed, then the color will be yellow and you will see the handler run at the end.

Comment: Oh right, does an Ansible copy only run if it would produce a change?

Comment: that is correct. It does all the md5sum stuff internally (or it uses another way - im not sure how this is done). Edit: you can think ansible as something that brings your server to a desired state. If you dont specify a change in state (by updating your config), then ansible will take no action